# Mulitcheckbox : I am able to check only one checkbox

Tags: angular, user-interface, checkbox, ngfor

There are 2 checkboxes displayed in a grid cell. I am able to check only one checkbox. If I click on the another, it' checking the first one. How to make the other checkbox active.
here is my html:

```
    <div class="inline-div" *ngFor="let item of to.labels | keyvalue; let idx=index">
<input type="checkbox" id="item{{item.value}}">
<label class="form-check-label" for="item{{item.value}}">{{item.value.value}}</label>
</div>
```

Please suggest how to make sure the other checkbox is been checked.

Comment: Please create stackblitz demo

Comment: Your `for="..."` and `id="..."` probably aren't being set correctly. Check in DevTools what their values are

Comment: @Drenai yup that was the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

id was not getting generated dynamically. So id's for both the checkbox were same. That's why only one checkbox were working.